# connection manager error while connecting to DB2 through SQOOP

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, db2, sqoop

Below is the sqoop command to list databases from DB2::

```
sqoop list-databases --connect  'jdbc:db2://DB_IP:PORT/' --username xxx --password xxx --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

But I get below error::

```
WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
```

What is the --connection-manager for DB2?

Changed sqoop syntax

```
sqoop import -libjars <path to>/db2jcc4.jar --connect 'jdbc:db2://DB_IP:PORT/' --username xxx -password xxx -m 1 --table db2_DB_name.db2_tbl_name --hive-overwrite --hive-import --hive-database amitesh_db --hive-table amitesh_db2test --target-dir <path_to>/db2test --as-parquetfile
```

Below is the error that I receive::

```
 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10165][10047][x.xx.xx] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://<db_ip>:<port>/. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10165][10047][4.17.28] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://<db_ip>:<port>/. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

Comment: Did you try `--connection-manager com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.Db2Manager ` and `--driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`  . You need to have recent db2jcc4.jar (from the latest )Db2-client for your operating-system) and possibly license file depending on target Db2-server operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the JDBC JARS, For DB2 you have to add the jars to /var/lib/sqoop and give the proper permissions. The log/error snapshot that you are showing is not an ERROR it's just a warning.

Please follow the below steps to add the jar and refer sqoop example to frame your sqoop code/command.

**1 >>>** Download the db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) or from where ever you can find.

**2 >>>** Push both the jars to /var/lib/sqoop across the cluster (data nodes and edge nodes) sqoop should have read and execute access to the jars.

Below is the sqoop example you can use, leverage the libjars part of the below code.

```
sqoop import -libjars /var/lib/sqoop/db2jcc.jar,/var/lib/sqoop/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar --connect 'jdbc:db2://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE_NAME>' --username xxxxxx -password xxxxx -m 1 --table ${DB2Schema}.${DB@Table} --hive-overwrite --hive-import --hive-database ${HIVE_DATABASE} --hive-table ${HIVE_TABLE} --target-dir ${HDFS_DIR} --as-parquetfile
```

Please note that sqoop doesn't support list database in DB2 database. Checkout in the official [sqoop doc](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_12).

Note: from sqoop document

> This only works with HSQLDB, MySQL and Oracle. When using with
>   Oracle, it is necessary that the user connecting to the database has
>   DBA privileges.

Comment: bases on your suggestion I made some changes to my sqoop syntax, but I am getting an error. I have added both of them in the original post

Comment: You need to change two things in your sqoop job, Add both the licence and JDBC jars to the libjars, same as I added in my example. the second one is your URL format is not right here is the syntax for it: jdbc:db2://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE_NAME>

Comment: @user3521180 I've changed the JDBC URL format in my answer as well